# PHP Curl request fails but works in other clients

Tags: php, curl

I have a very simple API request that sends a JSON encoded string with a userID and password. When I try to execute the command through my Chrome Extension - Advanced Request Client or through Swagger it works perfect, but the exact same request in CURL is failing, the response is returning invalid password.

The code should be really straight forward, is there some setting in CURL I'm missing?

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8080/api");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"userid\":\"1231\",\"password\":\"123\"}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
$headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
$headers[] = "X-Databasename: x";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: i don't believe you, but open a netcat server on port 8081, and change the request url to :8081  on both the chrome plugin and the curl code, and copypaste both results, the answer should be in comparing the 2

Comment: Doesn't matter what I do with CURL it will not work, there are no errors the API returns that the login credentials are incorrect. 

Do the same request using Advanced Rest Client and it works every time.

Here is the successful CURL request through Swagger, my code has replicated this in PHP and it will not work.

curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'X-DatabaseName: x' -d '{"userid":"1231","password":"123"}' 'http://localhost:8080/api'

Comment: open a netcat server, record the requests sent by both Swagger and by curl, i guarantee you will find differences in the request. for one, i guarantee that the `User-Agent:` header will be different (but because the User-Agent header is unlikely to be the issue, there are probably other differences too.)

Comment: another difference, ARC is almost certainly adding an `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br` header, your curl code is not. but that's also unlikely to be your issue, what other differences does the 2 requests have?